# Change LiveData source by updating a variable

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-databinding, android-livedata

I want the `LiveData` source for a `RecyclerView` to change depending on which list you selected. And that if you've selected a source in this search. 
At the moment I can't switch back and forth between the sources. So I can display items from my Room database, but I can't change the source if I've selected another list.

Example: If you selected List 2, the `LiveData` source will be changed and all items contained in that List 2 will be displayed. Now you should also be able to search for words in this list 2. How can you do this during the runtime of an app?

A part of my current `Repository`:

```
public LiveData<List<VocabularyEntity>> getVocabularies(int listNumber, String searchText) {
    if (listNumber == 0) {
        return listDao.getVocabularies(searchText);
    } else {
        return listDao.getVocabularyList(listNumber, searchText);
    }
}
```

And a part of my current `ViewModel`:

```
public LiveData<List<ListEntity>> getLists() {
    return repository.getLists(listNumber, searchText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any `setValue` or `getValue` function that is being called on your `LiveData` actually.

In order to change the `LiveData` to interact with the live changes, you need to call the `setValue` in your `LiveData` object. Something like the following should fix your problem here I think.

```
// I am assuming you have this variable declared in your viewmodel
private LiveData<List<ListEntity>> vocabList;

public LiveData<List<ListEntity>> getLists() {
    List<ListEntity> vocabListFromDB = repository.getLists(listNumber, searchText);
    vocabList.setValue(vocabListFromDB);

    return vocabList;
}
```

And you do not have to return the `LiveData` object from the repository function anymore.

```
public List<VocabularyEntity> getVocabularies(int listNumber, String searchText) {
    if(listNumber == 0) {
        return listDao.getVocabularies(searchText);
    } else {
        return listDao.getVocabularyList(listNumber, searchText);
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

I want to share my personal opinion on implementing this actually. I would rather have a `ContentObserver` instead of a `LiveData` setup. Implementation with a `ContentObserver` and a `CursorLoader` looks like an easier and robust solution in my humble opinion.